# get backup or get backed up?

Tags: grammar, phrase-usage

Which one is correct?

Data gets backup to your computer.

Data gets backed up to your computer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"backup" is a noun.

"to back up" is a verb.

I think you mean, "Data gets backed up to your computer."